# Download HTML content using node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to download the content of a HTML element (based on the class name of the element)  to my local system using node.js.

Could some one please share me the code snap for the same as I am new to node.js

HTML content of the same below

```html
<ul class="events">
    <!----><li id="zWcLsGMB9G6rDoeCS8zU" ng-repeat="event in events" on-last-repeat="" infinite-scroll="">
      <time>Jun 07 14:55:14</time>
      <span class="host"><a href="" ng-click="onHostSelected(event.hostname)"></a></span>
      <span class="program"><a ng-click="onProgramClick(event.program)">Response-Code: 200
:</a></span>
      <span class="message" ng-style="event.color? {color: event.color} : ''" ng-bind-html="event.message | ansiToHtml" compile-template=""><a class="ng-binding" ng-click="onClick('message','')"></a></span>
    </li><!----><li id="0GcLsGMB9G6rDoeCS8zU" ng-repeat="event in events" on-last-repeat="" infinite-scroll="">
      <time>Jun 07 14:55:14</time>
      <span class="host"><a href="" ng-click="onHostSelected(event.hostname)"></a></span>
      <span class="program"><a ng-click="onProgramClick(event.program)">Headers: {Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Content-Length=[795], content-type=[application/json; charset=UTF-8], Date=[Thu, 24 May 2018 12:36:00 GMT], Server=[Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)]}
:</a></span>
      <span class="message" ng-style="event.color? {color: event.color} : ''" ng-bind-html="event.message | ansiToHtml" compile-template=""><a class="ng-binding" ng-click="onClick('message','')"></a></span>
    </li><!----><li id="1GcLsGMB9G6rDoeCS8zU" ng-repeat="event in events" on-last-repeat="" infinite-scroll="">
      <time>Jun 07 14:55:14</time>
      <span class="host"><a href="" ng-click="onHostSelected(event.hostname)"></a></span>
      <span class="program"><a ng-click="onProgramClick(event.program)">  "relationship" : "http://10.0.3.91:7474/db/data/relationship",
:</a></span>
      <span class="message" ng-style="event.color? {color: event.color} : ''" ng-bind-html="event.message | ansiToHtml" compile-template=""><a class="ng-binding" ng-click="onClick('message','')"></a></span>
    </li><!----><li id="1WcLsGMB9G6rDoeCS8zU" ng-repeat="event in events" on-last-repeat="" infinite-scroll="">
      <time>Jun 07 14:55:14</time>
      <span class="host"><a href="" ng-click="onHostSelected(event.hostname)"></a></span>
      <span class="program"><a ng-click="onProgramClick(event.program)">  "node_index" : "http://10.0.3.91:7474/db/data/index/node",
:</a></span>
      <span class="message" ng-style="event.color? {color: event.color} : ''" ng-bind-html="event.message | ansiToHtml" compile-template=""><a class="ng-binding" ng-click="onClick('message','')"></a></span>
    </li><!----><li id="2GcLsGMB9G6rDoeCS8zU" ng-repeat="event in events" on-last-repeat="" infinite-scroll="">
      <time>Jun 07 14:55:14</time>
      <span class="host"><a href="" ng-click="onHostSelected(event.hostname)"></a></span>
      <span class="program"><a ng-click="onProgramClick(event.program)">  "relationship_types" : "http://10.0.3.91:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
:</a></span>
      <span class="message" ng-style="event.color? {color: event.color} : ''" ng-bind-html="event.message | ansiToHtml" compile-template=""><a class="ng-binding" ng-click="onClick('message','')"></a></span>
    </li><!---->
  </ul>
```

Comment: uhm we can't see any code

Comment: I added the HTML code now, I want the content of this HTML to be downloaded as a plain text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say this is your file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="hello-world">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And you want to save the contents of the class `hello-world` in a file using node, then you can get it by maybe by `document.getElementsByClassName('hello-world')` and pass it via a post request and in your nodejs server you can do something like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = req.body.data_from_client;
fs.writeFile('output.txt', data, function (err) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   console.log('File writing done');
});
```